# Can a maester's chain include multiple links of the same metal?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

A maester can be recognized by the chain he wears around his neck.
The links of the chain can be made of every metal known to man.
Each metal is related to a subject - silver for medicine, iron for warcraft, etc.
Can a maester's chain include multiple links of the same metal?

Comment: @Edlothiad: does EVERY answer to the other question also answer this one? (Clearly no.) So in what universe can the QUESTIONS be possibly considered duplicates, besides not this one?

Comment: [Meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11690/31394) about this question and its closure.

Comment: This is an egregious closure, the two questions are absolutely not duplicates.

Comment: @curiousdannii - The top answer to that question entirely answers this question. Indeed, the top answer here is basically a less detailed version of that answer. That makes them fairly strong dupe candidate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long does it take to forge a Maester's chain?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51260/how-long-does-it-take-to-forge-a-maesters-chain)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Yes.

[From George RR Martin himself](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Dragon_Limbs_and_Gender_Valyrain_Weapons_and_Maesters_Chains/), as referenced on [A Wiki of Ice and Fire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Maesters#cite_note-46):

> *Can a maester's chain include multiple links of the same metal?*
>
> Mulitple *[sic]* links are possible, and signify that the maester is especially accomplished in that area.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how could anyone wear a chain if it *didn't* have multiple links?

Comment: @Martha Multiple links *of the same metal* is the key here. Most maesters wear chains with one link of each of several different types of metal.

Answer (score 10):

According to this [SSM](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Dragon_Limbs_and_Gender_Valyrain_Weapons_and_Maesters_Chains/), Mulitple links are possible, and signify that the maester is especially accomplished in that area.

Comment: Please provide the information in your answer and not in the link.

Comment: @Edlothiad I think that's what "*Mulitple links are possible, and signify that the maester is especially accomplished in that area.*" is.

Comment: @NicHartley wow, I just opened the link and that really isn't a lot of information...

Comment: @Edlothiad I didn't open the link. I just looked at the answer.

Comment: @NicHartley in the case there is more information then just that line, the answer should really provide it in the post and not require users to go to links to read it. One line answers are rarely considered sufficient.

Comment: @Edlothiad For sure, but it's not a link-only answer, as your first comment implied.

Comment: @NicHartley I didn't say it was _link only_ I was just suggesting they provide more information from the link into the answer, but given there isn't more, that's unnecessary.

Comment: @Edlothiad while I agree that short answer are nto always the best, i decide to not edit the answer as it would made my answer a duplicate of Rand al'Thor's answer